# WCF Operation Performance Counters

Tags: wcf, performancecounter, performance

I want to use wcf performance counters per operation , like here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731052(v=vs.90).aspx

how can I add them to perfmon of windows service 2008 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you right click and say "Add Counters..." - there's a list of the different counters you can add, grouped up, the group name you are looking for is the one in bold in those articles, e.g.

- **ServiceModelEndpoint 4.0.0.0**  +
- **ServiceModelOperation 4.0.0.0** +
- **ServiceModelService 4.0.0.0**   +

It's not very clear from the documentation, I agree!